# Visual Basics not debugging new version of program

Tags: vb.net

This has been happening to me for a while now. Everytime I try debug my program it debugs the older version. Whenever I try build it it doesn't build at all and I get an error spammed 50 times.

> Message    53
>   Could not find type 'WindowsApplication28.Bloom'. Please make sure that the assembly that contains this type is referenced. If this type is a part of your development project, make sure that the project has been successfully built using settings for your current platform or Any CPU.       0   0

When I change the name of the program in the project settings, I get this error:

> ---------------------------
>   Microsoft Visual Studio
>   ---------------------------
>   Visual Studio cannot start debugging because the debug target 'C:\Users\Sam\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WindowsApplication28\WindowsApplication28\bin\Debug\Program1.exe' is missing. Please build the project and retry, or set the OutputPath and AssemblyName properties appropriately to point at the correct location for the target assembly.
>   ---------------------------
>   OK
>   ---------------------------

A few days ago I could change the name and debug it, and VB would automatically change the name of the program, but it's not doing it anymore. I have no idea what setting I've changed, because I don't remember touching anything.

Can someone please guide me in the right direction? I've worked hard on this and it's not working anymore =/

Comment: What do you have under `Tools - Options - Projects and Solutions - Build and Run`?

Comment: Here is a screenshot:
http://puu.sh/5RvXA.png

Comment: Well you have `Launch old version`, so here you go. Apparently you have build errors. Change to `Prompt` (the default).

Comment: @GSerg, I still get the error even after changing that.